# SSH error on linux - Permission denied, please try again

Tags: linux, ssh

I've looked at many similar questions and none of them help.  I'm trying to log in as root to my server but keep getting "Permission denied, please try again". I can log in via SSH fine on my other mac, just not on my new one.  I'm really new to keys and linux commands. Please help - I'm sure its something simple!

Comment: Are you logging with a password or with keys?  If you are using keys, did you add the key for your new computer to the `/root/ssh/authorized_keys` file on your server?

Comment: I'm logging in with a password.  It works on my laptop, but not on my desktop, both running OSX Mavericks, both on the same internet connection.

Comment: I have no idea why it's not letting me in with the password method. But - I followed the short tutorial on this page, and now I'm able to log in http://wiki.joyent.com/wiki/display/jpc2/Manually+Generating+your+SSH+Key+in+Mac+OS+X  I found it really hard to find a basic tutorial to help with this. You think there would be one out there.